# Read property value of interface, that is an int, but starting from the property name as a string

Tags: c#, interface, properties

I have a public interface named `API.Internals.IAccount`
It has an int as a property named `Number`

I can easily get the account number by calling Account.Number, but what I want is to find it's current value when I give him a string "Account.Number".
I'm trying to call it with:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.Account.GetType().GetField("Number").ToString());
```

But I get an object reference not set to an instance. I find this odd because I clearly state it's about `this.Account` at the beginning.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I've read a few interface guides but I'm having some trouble getting this trough

Comment: Please show the definition of the class and interface. Note that `ToString()` will not give you the current value anyway.

Comment: Use `GetProperty` instead of `GetField`.

Comment: Indeed, it was the get field that was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the *instance* (`this.Account` in your case) to read *property* from and call `GetValue`.

```
MessageBox.Show(this.Account.GetType()
  .GetProperty("Number")  // property, not field
  .GetValue(this.Account) // value of this.Account.Name
  .ToString());
```

Comment: Op writes that `Account` is the instance of an interface, hence it can't have any fields and `GetField` will always return null.

Comment: @SomeBody: Nice catch, thank you! `Number` is a property, not a field